# Jquery problem - cant expand the row above in a table

Tags: jquery

What I cant figure out is how I would toggle a row in a table using the one below it.

So say I have a table with 2 rows the first contains content and the one below contains a button, when the page loads the content row is hidden and when you click the button it toggles the content row on and off.

In the example the first table works but the second does not, I need the second one to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$(".sectionhead").toggle( 
    function() { 
            $(this).next("tr").hide(); 
    }, 
    function() { 
            $(this).next("tr").show(); 
    } 
)
```

});

Comment: Don't you mean `.prev("tr")`?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `.prev()` instead of `.next()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".sectionhead").toggle(
  function() {
   $(this).prev().hide();
  },
  function() {
   $(this).prev().show();
  }
 )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".sectionhead").each(function() {
        $(this).toggle( 
            function() { 
                $(this).next("tr").hide(); 
            }, 
            function() { 
                $(this).next("tr").show(); 
            } 
        ) 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$(function() { 
  $("table").delegate(".sectionhead", "click", function() { 
    $(this).next("tr").toggle(); 
  });
});
```

If the table is dynamically loaded though, you'll need this:

```
$(function() { 
  $(".sectionhead").live("click", function() { 
    $(this).next("tr").toggle(); 
  });
});
```